# Simplifying $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+1)(n+2)(z^n+z^{n+1})}$

Tags: calculus, summation

This is part of a larger problem where I am trying to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+1)^2z^n}=(z+1)/(1-z)^3$. Thus far I have used the derivatives of the geometric series to obtain $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+1)(n+2)(z^n+z^{n+1})}$ which I know is equivalent to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+1)^2z^n}$ but I'm not at all sure how one would come to such a conclusion. I assume it has something or other to do with shifting the indexes but I have not been clever enough to find a trick to give what I need.

Any help in simplifying the aforementioned series would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Notice that $n(n+1) + (n+1)(n+2) = 2(n+1)^2$. Hence those series are equivalent.

Comment: You also have to shift the index ... $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}z^n$.  And perhaps do the case $n=0$ separately.

Comment: If you take $\sum z^{n+1}$, differentiate, multiply by $z$, differentiate again, you get $\sum(n+1)^2z^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to both of the commenters, by combining these observations I have found a solution namely:

$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+1)(n+2)(z^n+z^{n+1})} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n(n+1)z^{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(n+2)(n+1)z^{n}} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(n+1)(2n+2)z^n} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(n+1)^2z^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+1)^2z^n}$

as desired.